# how to temporary store the textbox value using JQuery

Tags: jquery

How to temporary store the textbox value until I close the browser using JQuery Please help me with the code

Comment: Where you want to store ? client side or server side ?

Comment: The question is too vague, redsquare answer explains why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to store the data on the client, then put it in a Cookie the [jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) plugin makes this really easy.

```
$.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'beans')
```

Answer (score 1):

use [.data](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data)

```
var $input = $('#inputId');

$input.data('persist', $input.val() );
```

Comment: The question is so vague that your answer is valid for me. Obviusly your answer is still correct for this.